# Replace words in text with words generated using all_words

Tags: r, text-mining, qdap

Being pretty new to `qdap`, I am not sure whether this functionality is present, but it would be great to have something as mentioned below.

My initial dataset.

```
ID         Keywords
1          112 mills, open heart surgery, great, great job
2          Ausie, open, heart out
3          opened, heartily, 56mg)_job, orders12
4          order, macD
```

On using `all_words()` I end up with the following data.

```
   WORD     FREQ
1  great       2
2  heart       2
3  open        2
4  ausie       1
5  heartily    1
6  job         1
7  macd        1
8  mgjob       1
9  mills       1
10 opened       1
11 order        1
12 orders       1
13 out          1
14 surgery      1
```

Is there a way in which the main dataset can be replaced by the exact words that are appearing through `all_words()`?

edit1:
So the list that comes from using all_words() should replace the original words in the dataframe, i.e 112 mills should become mills, 56mg)_job should become mgjob.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want any strings with numbers?

Comment: Can you please try and explain it better? It is not clear what you need. Also, making your example reproducible can go a long way in getting you help. Bonus for elaborating a bit on `all_words` function

Comment: Try `un1 <- unlist(strsplit(df1$Keywords, "[, ]"));  as.data.frame(table(grep("^[A-Za-z]+$", un1, value = TRUE)))`

Comment: @akrun - Getting the frequency list is not a problem. Problem is replacing the original words from which this list has been derived with the words in the list. i.e 56mg)_job should become mgjob  on row number 3. Hope this helps in explaining the situation better

Comment: @Jishu, could you please look at my answer (esp. 3rd edit) and provide some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit more manual and I do not know how your data are formatted, but with some tinkering should do the work:

**Edit: and it is not using `qdap`, but I have assumed this is not a crucial part of the question.**

**2nd edit: I forgot about the substitution, corrected code below.**

```
library(data.table)
library(tm)  # Functions with tm:: below
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(
  ID = 1L:4L,
  Keywords = c(
    paste('112 mills', 'open heart', 'surgery', 'great', 'great job', sep = ' '),
    paste('Ausie', 'open', 'heart out', sep = ' '),
    paste('opened', 'heartily', '56mg)_job', 'orders12', sep = ' '),
    paste('order', 'macD', sep = ' ')))

# dt_2 <- data.table(Tokens = tm::scan_tokenizer(dt[, Keywords]))
dt_2 <- dt[, .(Tokens = unlist(strsplit(Keywords, split = ' '))), by = ID]

dt_2[, Words := tm::scan_tokenizer(Tokens) %>%
       tm::removePunctuation() %>%
       tm::removeNumbers()
     ]
dt_2[, Stems := tm::stemDocument(Words)]

dt_2
#     ID    Tokens    Words    Stems
#  1:  1       112                  
#  2:  1     mills    mills     mill
#  3:  1      open     open     open
#  4:  1     heart    heart    heart
#  5:  1   surgery  surgery  surgeri
#  6:  1     great    great    great
#  7:  1     great    great    great
#  8:  1       job      job      job
#  9:  2     Ausie    Ausie     Ausi
# 10:  2      open     open     open
# 11:  2     heart    heart    heart
# 12:  2       out      out      out
# 13:  3    opened   opened     open
# 14:  3  heartily heartily heartili
# 15:  3 56mg)_job    mgjob    mgjob
# 16:  3  orders12   orders    order
# 17:  4     order    order    order
# 18:  4      macD     macD     macD

# Frequencies
dt_2[, .N, by = Words]
#        Words N
#  1:          1
#  2:    mills 1
#  3:     open 2
#  4:    heart 2
#  5:  surgery 1
#  6:    great 2
#  7:      job 1
#  8:    Ausie 1
#  9:      out 1
# 10:   opened 1
# 11: heartily 1
# 12:    mgjob 1
# 13:   orders 1
# 14:    order 1
# 15:     macD 1
```

**2nd edit here:**

```
res <- dt_2[, .(Keywords = paste(Words, collapse = ' ')), by = ID]
res
#    ID                                  Keywords
# 1:  1  mills open heart surgery great great job
# 2:  2                      Ausie open heart out
# 3:  3              opened heartily mgjob orders
# 4:  4                                order macD
```

**3rd edit, in case your keywords come as lists and you would like to keep them that way.**

```
library(data.table)
library(tm)  # Functions with tm:: below
library(magrittr)

dt <- data.table(
  ID = 1L:4L,
  Keywords = list(
    c('112 mills', 'open heart', 'surgery', 'great', 'great job'),
    c('Ausie', 'open', 'heart out'),
    c('opened', 'heartily', '56mg)_job', 'orders12'),
    c('order', 'macD')))

dt_2 <- dt[, .(Keywords = unlist(Keywords)), by = ID]
dt_2[, ID_temp := .I]

dt_3 <- dt_2[, .(ID, Tokens = unlist(strsplit(unlist(Keywords), split = ' '))), by = ID_temp]

dt_3[, Words := tm::scan_tokenizer(Tokens) %>%
       tm::removePunctuation() %>%
       tm::removeNumbers() %>%
       stringr::str_to_lower()
     ]
dt_3[, Stems := tm::stemDocument(Words)]
dt_3

res <- dt_3[, .(
  ID = first(ID),
  Keywords = paste(Words, collapse = ' ') %>% stringr::str_trim()),
  by = ID_temp]
res <- res[, .(Keywords = list(Keywords)), by = ID]

# Confirm format (a list of keywords in every element)
dt[1, Keywords] %T>% {print(class(.))} %T>% {print(length(.[[1]]))}
res[1, Keywords] %T>% {print(class(.))} %T>% {print(length(.[[1]]))}
```

Comment: @m-dz- The second edit only made life easy for me.thanks a lot .....its just that my csv contains multiple space separated words which should be considered as single word. ie, [heart surgery, specificity, sick as hell ]should be considered as 3 words instead of 6.